# informat $DATE was not found or could not be loaded in sas

Tags: sas

i have dataset a

```
data a;
input cc enrolled;
cards;
1 13-oct-01;
2 15-dec-04;
3 20-dec-04;
4 24-dec-10;
run;
```

we have to find year & month from enrolled variable.
i am using this code

```
data yr;
set secondfile;
format Enrolled mmddyy10.;
informat Enrolled date9.;
yea=year(Enrolled);
mnth=month(Enrolled);
run;
```

receive the error The format $MMDDYY was not found or could not be loaded &

The informat $DATE was not found or could not be loaded

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those errors occur because you are attempting to apply a numeric informat to a character variable.  Presumably `enrolled` is a character variable, rather than a numeric SAS Date variable.  You cannot convert a character variable to numeric simply by specifying `informat`; you need to actually use `input` and use a differently named target variable.

```
data yr;
  set secondfile;
  enrolled_n = input(enrolled,date9.);
  yea = year(enrolled_n);
  mnth= month(enrolled_n);
run;
```